# Python3 Socket Programming with SSL errors?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I'm just learning the basics of Python socket programming and secure networking. I've connected two VM's on my network, and I want to see the difference between encrypted vs. non-encrypted messages in Wireshark. So, I followed these tutorials https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309 and https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#server-side-operation and https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#server-side-operation to set up some openSSL certificates for my server VM, and I copied the rootCA certificate to my client VM.

These are the commands I followed to create my self-signed certificates:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

When it asked for a Common Name, I gave it the IP of my server, which is 172.25.1.5.

However, when I try to run my server and client python scripts, I get these errors:

```
$ python3 server.py 
what is host? 172.25.1.5
server bound.
server listening
Accepted conn from: ('172.25.1.4', 59592)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 32, in <module>
    connstream = context.wrap_socket(conn,server_side=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:852)
```

On the client side, I see:

```
$ python3 client.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 19, in <module>
    s.connect((host,port))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1109, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1100, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```

Here's my code for the server and client:

```
import os, socket, ssl

# host and port
host = "172.25.1.5" # my VM ip
port = 1234
print("what is host? " + host)

# create context for socket (with ssl security)
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="server.crt",keyfile="server.key")

# create socket and bind the socket to a tuple of host,port
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))
print("server bound.")

# listen for connections. The normal max is 5. The slides have 1.
print("server listening")
s.listen(1)

# accept connection
conn,address = s.accept()
print("Accepted conn from: " + str(address))

# give connection context
connstream = context.wrap_socket(conn,server_side=True)
#connstream = conn
print("wrapped socket.")

# receive data loop
# breaks if no data received
while True:
    data = connstream.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
        break
    print("received from client: " + str(data))
    # echo back
    connstream.send(data.encode())
connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
connstream.close()
conn.close()
```

And here's my client script on a different VM:

```
import os, socket, ssl

# get context
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_verify_locations("rootCA.crt")
# define host and port
host = "172.25.1.5" #ip of linked clone
port = 1234

# make socket and connect to tuple host,port. Wrap socket in context
s = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),server_hostname=host)
s.connect((host,port))

cert = s.getpeercert()
print("What is cert? " +str(cert))
print("\n\n")
# get input
msg = input("out: ")

# Receive msg loop and send loop
while msg.lower().strip() != '':
    s.send(msg.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()

    print("In: " + data)

    msg = input("Out: ")

s.close()
```

I am stuck. I've made sure that my code follows the examples. How do I get around these errors? Is there something I'm missing?

Any help or explanation is appreciated. I'm still just learning.

Comment: If you're just trying to play with SSL and learn the basics, you definitely do not want anything to do with client certificates.

Comment: I only have server certificates. The client only has access to a self-signed certificate I used to create the server keys and certificates.

Comment: I was following a tutorial, and that's the code snippet it had with an explanation that it should work if I only have server certificates that the client would check for validity. The server shouldn't check the client.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode  by default it is CERT_REQUIRED, so the server will ask the client for a certificate, and then it doesn't know about the CA that signed this certificate hence the TLS CA error from the server side, that means client certificate not verified as reported by the client side.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica `Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH` is completely fine, see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#server-side-operation . The problem is the `verify_mode` default setting.

Comment: So, in that part, I want to make a server-side socket that will echo what I get from the client. Should I just leave the argument for ssl.create_default_context() empty?

Comment: So, how would I change the verify_mode to not requiring a certificate? Would it be context.verify_mode = CERT_NONE ?

Comment: I tried putting context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE in server.py right after I create the default context. I'm still get the same error.

Comment: Separate: you reference "https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#server-side-operation " aka python2 but then you launch your software with python3. Make sure you are looking at the corresponding documentation for your Python version, specifically in TLS land, things do change over time.

Comment: Also probably simpler: no need of a root CA, you can just use a self signed certificate for the server, and it will be the rootCA of the client also.

Comment: That is what rootCA.crt is. I self-signed a certificate on the server side and then copied it onto the client side. Thank you for pointing out that I was using python2 documentation, though! I didn't notice the difference, but I will check through python 3 documentation and fix my code accordingly. So far, the python2 and python3 code looks almost identical in both tutorials.

Comment: I checked through my code to follow the python3 tutorial you linked (docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#server-side-operation). The error is still the same.

Comment: "I self-signed a certificate on the server side and then copied it onto the client side." Then what the client uses as "root CA" to check the server certificate should exactly be the certificate the server is using to identify itself (as it is self signed so it is its own CA). At least the names do not match in your examples (but maybe the content does)

Comment: I will try that. But wouldn't any certificate signed by rootCA be verifiable? So, rootCA is self-signed, but using rootCA I created a key and certificate for my server called server.crt and server.key. That is, server.crt and server.key is signed by rootCA.crt.

Comment: I was using this tutorial to make a self signed root certificate and a certificate for my server. https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309

Comment: Doing what you suggested worked! However, I still want to try to get the server certificate to be verifiable. Do i need to recreate another server certificate signed by rootCA.crt? It's possible that something went wrong when I created my server certificate.

Comment: "So, rootCA is self-signed, but using rootCA I created a key and certificate for my server called server.crt and server.key." It can work like that indeed, I was just saying that to start a single self signed certificate may be simpler than a whole "fake" CA setup. But both cases should work technically.

Comment: "It's possible that something went wrong when I created my server certificate. " Probably better to show exactly the commands you typed when create crypto materials (even if you followed a specific tutorial, that link can disappear any time so it makes your question not having all data). Or just start from scratch and see again. You can post your results as an answer so that it would help others and then just mark the question as answered.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Following Patrick Mevzek's advice in the comments, I tried changing the line

```
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="server.crt",keyfile="server.key")
```

to

```
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="rootCA.crt",keyfile="rootCA.key")
```

That worked, and that told me that something went wrong when I created the server.crt and server.key. So, I simply deleted server.key, server.csr, and server.crt in the server VM and recreated them using

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

After recreating them, I could use server.crt and server.key as the certfile and keyfile.

Using either my fake CA setup with server.crt or just directly using rootCA for SSL works for encrypting my messages, and using Wireshark also verified that.

I appreciate everyone's help, and I hope this answer helps others who encounter this problem when playing around with socket programming and SSL.